# Form Post data using Ajax and jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, html

I have a Form

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="result.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
<form name="form" method="POST" id="form">
    <input type="text" value="" id="htno" name="htno" Maxlength="12" style="width:165px;" class="bodytext"></input>
    <input type="button" value="Submit">
</form>
<div id="result" class="result"></div>
```

And  result.js file is

```
$("#form").submit(function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $("#result").html('');
    var values = $(this).serialize();
    $.ajax({
        url: "url",
        type: "post",
        data: "htno=" + htno + "&code=2132",
        success: function () {
            alert("success");
            $("#result").html('submitted successfully');
        },
        error: function () {
            alert("failure");
            $("#result").html('there is error while submit');
        }
    });
});
```

htno is the value the user enters through form

Data to be posted is htno & code

i am unable to get output using this, please can u tell me the fault . . . .

Comment: What is the console telling you? Have you tried putting jquery.js before result.js?

Comment: Can you tell us what your console think about your code?

Comment: <<yah its not working >> ok, great news! But wait, what means not working actually?

Comment: Someone post here when their code is not working ..tell something new and post what console is saying..

Comment: the url gives a 404, are you sure about that?, also I think that jquery.js should be before the result.js

Comment: i am getting nothing, just blank

Comment: yah that url only works after posting the data

Comment: Seriously @user2442316, how many times will you ask on SO how to steal data from sites which is not yours???

Answer (score 1):

You should know that a form is submitted when the input type is submit.In your code change the type of button to submit.

just change the part

```
<input type="button"  value="Submit" >
```

to

```
 <input type="submit"  value="Submit" >
```

and in your result.js remove this line

```
event.preventDefault();
```

because this line prevent your form from submitting without any reason.

Comment: thank you, Now i m getting a alert "failure", that means the data is failing to post

Comment: yes.because you have given url:"url";. give a valid url and echo something.

Comment: no actually i m giving url in my localhost, i just dont want to display url here

Comment: check what is posted by $_POST['htno'] and $_POST['code'] in your URL then echo these.

Answer (score 0):

try changing your

```
 $("#form").submit(function(event) {
 event.preventDefault();
```

by

```
$(document).on('submit','#form',function(e) {
e.preventDefault();
```

alto, try to alert data

Comment: the problem, you dont pass the htno to you jquery function.
try this "var htno = $('input[name=htno ]');"

Answer (score 0):

The page you are trying to connect use temporary tokens. You cannot do what you are looking for. You are not allowed to do it. Ask owner of site for kind of API access, he could make you a good price...  `{ this topic should be closed! }`

Comment: Because iframe makes it like you are a valid user, setting tokens on server. Have you ask the owner authorization to use his datas? I don't think so...